# BDD Test Plans: Should features be the same User Stories?

Tags: bdd, acceptance-testing

So I'm somewhat new to the BDD world. I've been using Cucumber a little bit for automated testing, but I'm unable to automate everything due to general manpower/time restrictions. However, as I write acceptance test plans from User Stories I'm trying to keep them in the Gherkin format (hopefully that's right? let me know if that's the "wrong way" to go about it).

I'm using Testrail right now, as each "test case" is going to be a 'feature'. (ideally, I can then turn these into automated tests down the road easily).

That being said, should each user stories be mapped 1:1 to a "feature" (aka acceptance test cases)? Or can a feature contain multiple user stories (in the form of scenarios maybe)?

Hopefully what I'm saying makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience at work a feature is a user story. There's a 1:1 relationship between a feature (as in Specflow) and a user story (as in BDD).